# Контекст THIS, как сделать функцию универсальной?

Tags: javascript, jquery

объясните непонимающему контекст THIS, **как мне сделать данную функцию универсальной**, имею представление о том как работет THIS, но не имею представления как использовать эту фичу в данном примере. Допустим таких разделов **с одинаковыми классами** на странице будет 3-4 штуки, не писать же под каждый раздел свою функцию.

p.s прошу не ругать за код, учусь, пишу как умею, все с чего то начинали.

```js
otherItemsLoad(".container",".item", ".loadMore");

function otherItemsLoad(selector, item, loadButton){

 //Начальное значение для отображения 3 item
 ic = 3;
  
 var items = $(selector).children(item);

 //Подгрузка по клику
 $(loadButton).click(function(){
  ic += 4; // Еще +4 item
  loads();
 });

 function loads(){

  for(i = 0; i < ic; i++){
   //Показываем item
   items.eq(i).show();

   //Отключаем кнопку
   if(ic >= items.length){
    $(loadButton).css({
     "opacity": "0.3",
     "pointer-events": "none"
    });
   }
  }
 }
 loads();
}
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item{
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}
.loadMore{
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="loadMore">ЗАГРУЗИТЬ</div>
</div>
```

Comment: причем тут `this`, если в коде он нигде не используется?

Comment: Извините, при чем здесь `this`?

Comment: @Grundy, в том то и дело что я хочу его использовать, но не пойму как его в данном случае применить, если таких разделов с одинаковыми классами на странице будет несколько

Comment: @Vearo это все конечна можно лучше написать, но `this` это ваш текущий объект, его использовать конечна можно, но он не всегда нужен, так вот, "**с одинаковыми классами на странице будет 3-4 штуки**" вы думали про добавление идентификаторов?

Comment: @Dmitry думал, но хочу решить данный вопрос именно в таком виде, возможно больше пойму работу THIS

Comment: @Vearo мой вам совет, возьмите просто посмотрите, что в `this` находится, я думаю тогда Вы все поймете.

Можно вот тут: 
`
$(loadButton).click(function(){
  ic += 4; // Еще +4 item
                console.log(this);
  loads();
 });
`

Comment: _Допустим таких разделов с одинаковыми классами_ - о каких конкретно классах идет речь?

Comment: @Grundy о .container в котором лежат .item, что если таких контейнеров с item будет несколько? хочу чтобы данная функция работала на каждый такой контейнер по отдельности.

Comment: @Grundy В данном же случае можно прокликивать до тех пор, пока все .item во всех .container не покажутся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы применить функцию к **каждому** элементу в выборке нужно воспользоваться методом [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

В это случае внутри переданного callback `this` будет указывать на текущий элемент. Все остальное можно оставить как есть, например:

```js
otherItemsLoad(".container", ".item", ".loadMore");

function otherItemsLoad(selector, item, loadButton) {

  $(selector).each(function() {

    //Начальное значение для отображения 3 item
    var ic = 3;
    var container = $(this); // говорим что container - текущий элемент
    var items = container.children(item);

    //Подгрузка по клику
    container.find(loadButton).click(function() {
      ic += 4; // Еще +4 item
      loads();
    });

    function loads() {

      for (var i = 0; i < ic; i++) {
        //Показываем item
        items.eq(i).show();

        //Отключаем кнопку
        if (ic >= items.length) {
          container.find(loadButton).css({
            "opacity": "0.3",
            "pointer-events": "none"
          });
        }
      }
    }
    loads();
  });

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}

.loadMore {
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="loadMore">ЗАГРУЗИТЬ</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="loadMore">ЗАГРУЗИТЬ</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Думал в сторону each